# Javascript works in Chrome and Firefox but not IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

this is my first time posting on this site and I'm not a developer. But it's my first time coding a calculator for a work tool and I am having some difficulties on making this work on IE11. Here is my [codepen.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GydyjW)

Whenever I test the calculator on Chrome and Firefox, it does the full calculation correctly, but on IE11, I believe it won't perform this function which calculates the amount that is not used yet:

```
function Unutilized() {
  var unused_amount = document.getElementById("unusedCred").value;
  var unused_WA;
  var unused_WaB;
  var CustomerInt;
  var RateUsedQ12;

  document.getElementById("RateUsedQ12").innerHTML = AddedRate + PremiumOver;
  CustomerInt = document.getElementById("RateUsedQ12").value;
  RateUsedQ12 = (+CustomerInt) + (+StressRatePrem);
  document.getElementById("RateUsedQ12").innerHTML = RateUsedQ12;
  if (RateUsedQ12 > StandardRate) {
    document.getElementById("RateUsedQ12").innerHTML = RateUsedQ12;
  unused_WA = (RateUsedQ12 / 100) * unused_amount;
    document.getElementById("WeightAvg12").innerHTML = unused_WA.toFixed(0);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("RateUsedQ12").innerHTML = StandardRate;
unused_WaB =
      StandardRate / 100 * document.getElementById("unusedCred").value;

    document.getElementById("WeightAvg12").innerHTML = unused_WaB.toFixed(0);
  }
```

I noticed that if this function does not work, then the final calculation will not show as well, instead the Unused Credit and Calculated Rate will show NAN.

I also noticed when I select product 4, product 5 and Other, the Rate Used column will not display 6.20% which messes up another part of the calculation in IE.

```
else if (x == "Pro4" || x == "Pro5" || x == "Other") {
document.getElementById("RateUsedQ1").innerHTML = AddedRate + PremiumOver;
CustomerInt = document.getElementById("RateUsedQ1").value;
RateUsedQ = (+CustomerInt) + (+StressRatePrem);
document.getElementById("RateUsedQ1").innerHTML = RateUsedQ;
if (RateUsedQ > StandardRate) {
  document.getElementById("RateUsedQ1").innerHTML = RateUsedQ;

  WeightAvr = RateUsedQ / 100 * document.getElementById("AdvCred").value;
  document.getElementById("WeightAvg").innerHTML = WeightAvr;
} else {
  document.getElementById("RateUsedQ1").innerHTML = StandardRate;

  WeightAvr = StandardRate / 100 * document.getElementById("AdvCred").value;
  document.getElementById("WeightAvg").innerHTML = WeightAvr;
}
```

I tried to look at other stackoverflow questions similar to my problems, but I honestly have no idea how to fix these problems.

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Just go step by step. IE11 doesnt allow some es5 functions and definitively not es6

Comment: You must be getting some errors in your console.  Tell us what they are.

Comment: There's a lot to be debugged but at a quick grasp it looks like the issue resides in a mathematical operation on strings or `undefined` values rather than on integers/floats. You will have to start debugging your code and a tip is to ensure that you always convert the value to integers or floats if you are going to do any sort of math ops on them.